# How to turn on Front flashlight(not the rear one) of a android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera, flashlight

I developed a simple application to turn ON/OFF flashlight. But I couldn't find a way to **turn on front flashlight** of a device(if available).

Code for availability check :

```
boolean hasCameraFlash = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

My code for turn ON is :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void flashLightOn() {
    try {
        String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
    } catch (CameraAccessException ignored) {
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to turn on front flashlight of device without turning on camera.
Any help will be appreciated.**

(Please note that I'm a newcomer to android development)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give 1 in your getCameraIdList. As getCameraIdList() contains only 2 values ie 0 for back camera and 1 for front camera.

```java
String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
 cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

It worked for me.